# Laravel Redirect with

Tags: php

I got a problem when trying to redirect back with some results from my sql. 
I got a function:

```
public function postSearch() {
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
            'search' => 'required'
            )
        );


        if($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::route('search')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        } else {
            $search = Input::get('search');

            $user = User::where('username', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->get();

            if($user->count() >= 1) {
                return Redirect::route('search')
                    ->with('user', $user)
                    ->withInput();
            } else {
                return Redirect::route('search')
                    ->with('global', 'Could not find user.')
                    ->withInput();
            }
        }

        return Redirect::route('search')
            ->with('global', 'Something went wrong, try again later.');
    }
```

but when select was successful in other my file with this code:

```
@foreach ($user as $users)
            <p>
                <a href="{{ URL::route('profile-user', $users->username) }}">$users->username</a>;
            </p>
            @endforeach
```

i got exception undefined user variable. But when i trying to search what doesnt exists in table, 'global' attribute showing my message.

Any ideas why is that not working?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your error is just fine. The `$user` variable is not defined so you can't iterate over it.

There are 2 things you can do. In your view, you can check if the variable is set

```
@if (isset($user)

    @foreach ($user as $users)
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endforeach

@endif
```

You can also set a default value on your code, but you will also need to **always** your variable to the view. For example:

```
$user = array();

return Redirect::route('search')
    ->with('user', $user)
    ->with('global', 'Could not find user.')
    ->withInput();

// you will need the $user on your last redirect too
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: thats the problem with function i find a user but i cant print it. All time show exception undefined user variable.

Comment: You can't print something that is not defined. Somehow your `$user` doesn't get to your view.

Comment: I found the other way how to fix this :) im just using $user = Session::get('user'), but i used same method before in this project and its work for me fine.